# Second monitor shows black screen or poor quality image

Tags: graphic-drivers, microsoft-windows, intel

When I try to connect a monitor to the laptop it either shows a black screen or a poor quality image. By poor quality I mean discoloration and some static  at the outer left and right sides. The black screen appears when I try to drag some window to the monitor.

I checked the monitor using another laptop. It works just fine. I also checked the laptop, connecting it to a TV, everything also worked fine.

I thought it might be because of the drivers, but intel support tells me my drivers are up to date.

The was also some recommendation to go to intel graphics and change quantization rate to full, which I did. It didn't help.

Amusingly when I connect the TV to the second laptop it shows the same poor quality image(but without the black screen).

I use the same hdmi cable for every case.

My laptop laptop is an acer aspire v 13 with intel hd 520.

The monitor is also an acer.

Both have 1920 by 1080 definition if it matters.

The second monitor is an HP with a intel hd 620 and definition of 1366 by 768.

Even when the monitor shows black screen the laptop still sees it.
Both have windows 10 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has an issue with it's driver enumerators, not just for some display combinations, but Realtek audio and some Bluetooth as well. The've been slowly...very slowly..working it out. Until they handle it, or someone else figures it out, the easiest solution is to change drivers whenever you change devices, manually. Don't listen to what you're told, find your own drivers.